# Multivalue parametres in SSRS- display in the report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, multivalue

I just started working with SSRS, so this question might seem silly.

Anyway, for now I'm trying to avoid multi-valued parameters, because I want my parameters to be able to be NULL. So I'm just passing a comma-separated string of ID values to my stored procedure, and everything works. 
The problem I encountered is that I want to display the actual values, not IDs, in the report, so that users can see, what filter was used.
If that were a multi-valued parameter, I would simply use JOIN function, but now I am out of ideas and would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a multivalue parameter as null. You can use xxxx.label rather than xxxx.value in the report.